# How to schedule task for start of every hour

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I'm developing a service that suppose to start of every hour repeating exactly on the hour (1:00PM, 2:00PM, 3:00PM, etc.).

I tried following but it has one problem that for first time i have to run the program exactly at start of hour and then this scheduler will repeat it.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new MyTask(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Any suggestion to repeat my task regardless when i run the program?

Regards,
Imran

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would also suggest [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) for this. But the above code can be made to run first at the start of the hour using the initialDelay parameter.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), millisToNextHour(calendar), 60*60*1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);



private static long millisToNextHour(Calendar calendar) {
    int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int millis = calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    int minutesToNextHour = 60 - minutes;
    int secondsToNextHour = 60 - seconds;
    int millisToNextHour = 1000 - millis;
    return minutesToNextHour*60*1000 + secondsToNextHour*1000 + millisToNextHour;
}
```

Comment: we will use scheduleWithFixedDelay or scheduleAtFixedDelay ? i think we will use scheduleAtFixedDelay. otherwise it will add execution time in repetition.

Comment: yes. in your case you should use scheduleAtFixedRate. Updated the answer

Comment: This is helpful but note that this code will run the task 1 minute and 1 second later than the beginning of an hour.

Answer (score 10):

The `millisToNextHour` method in krishnakumarp's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10204932/423991) can be made more compact and straightforward in Java 8, which would result in the following code:

```
public void schedule() {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduledExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), millisToNextHour(), 60*60*1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

private long millisToNextHour() {
    LocalDateTime nextHour = LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(1).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);
    return LocalDateTime.now().until(nextHour, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you can afford to use an external library, then [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) provides very flexible and easy to use scheduling modes. For example `cron` mode should be perfect for your case. Below a simple example of scheduling a certain [Job](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/Job.html) to be executed every hour:

```
quartzScheduler.scheduleJob(
    myJob, newTrigger().withIdentity("myJob", "group")
                       .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 * * * * ?")).build());
```

Have a look at the [tutorial](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/) and [examples](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/) to find which formulations suits your tastes. They also show how to deal with errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the spring in your service than you can directly use the annotation based scheduler @Schedule annotation which takes cron expression as a parameter or the delay in milliseconds, just add this annotation above the method you want to execute and this method will be executed. Enjoy...........

Comment: In case of using Spring / ... just additional info: If you are running multiple instance make sure that schedulers are capable of running in parallel or use different profiles / deployments / thread-safe single runners / Shedlock / ... otherwise It can lead to parallel output, DB blockings etc which lead to inconsistencies, missleading error traces or redundent user notifications

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing an Java EE application, not necessarily using Spring (as indicated in @deepmoteria's answer), you can also use the @Schedule annotation.

See [Scheduling in Jakarta EE](https://www.baeldung.com/scheduling-in-java-enterprise-edition).