# How to schedule jobs in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, job-scheduling

I am new to hadoop, I have written few jobs and exported them as jar file . I am able to run them  using hadoop jar command, I want to run these jobs every one hour . How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Hadoop itself doesn't have ways to schedule jobs like you are suggesting.  So you have two main choices, Java's Time and scheduling functions, or run the jobs from the operating system, I would suggest [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). I would personally use cron to do this, it's simple and very flexible, and is installed by default on most servers. There are also lots of tutorials.

Cron example to run on the first minute of every hour.

```
0 * * * *  /bin/hadoop jar myJar.jar
```

If you want to keep it inside of java itself, I would suggest checking out this question which has details and code, [How to schedule task for start of every hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204246/how-to-schedule-task-for-start-of-every-hour).

Answer (score 3):

You could probably achieve that by writing a cron or some script. But the better way, in my view, would be to use some scheduler like [Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to an already mentioned Oozie, you might want to take a look at [Falcon](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop/falcon/).

From own experience, however, a much easier approach is to try using your CI system to avoid adding new systems to your stack, for example [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/)

Comment: This may not be a good suggestion since the purpose of Falcon & Jenkins are both different from what the OP wants. Also, Jenkins may not be available at client sites. I would recommend Tariq's & greedybuddha's answers.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another option to CRON & Oozie, [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)